# Rating bar in android - Reset value

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am using rating bar to mark a field as favorite. The user should be able to unmark it some time in future. But once i set it, the on-click listener is not working on that item.

XML code

```
<RatingBar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:numStars="1"
android:stepSize="1"
android:id="@+id/fav"/>
```

JAVA code

```
fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ //fav is a ratingbar
        public void onClick(View view){
            favRest = !favRest; //A boolean variable which is set/reset each time it is clicked
            if(favRest)
            {   fav.setRating(1.0f);
                addFav(uname,hotelName);

            }
            else{
                fav.setRating(0.0f);
                removeFav(uname,hotelName);

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you `rate`, its not possible to `clear` rate using touch on `RatingBar`. You can only change rate value from 1.`0 to 5.0`.

To `clear/reset` rate value, you have to use other action like adding a `Clear/Reset` `Button`.

In `Button` click listener, you can `reset` rating value by using `setRating(0.0)`

```
 resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Reset
            ratingBar.setRating(0.0);
        }
    });
```

**UPDATED:**

In your `RatingBar`, you are using `android:numStars="1"` and `android:stepSize="1"`. So once you `rate 1` its not possible to `rate 0` by using touch on `RatingBar`

**From my point of view:**

1. You can use `ImageView` instead of `RatingBar`
2. Add two different icons for `favorite` and `unfavorite` in `res/drawable` folder
3. Set desired icon to `ImageView` as per checking `favRest` value.

**Try This:**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/fav" />


imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fav);
fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ //fav is a ratingbar
    public void onClick(View view){
        favRest = !favRest; //A boolean variable which is set/reset each time it is clicked
        if(favRest)
        {   
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite);
            addFav(uname,hotelName);
        } 
        else
        {
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_unfavorite);                
            removeFav(uname,hotelName);
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: yes, you are correct. But once I set it, the on-click listener doesn't work on that item.

Comment: Posted, Once it gets set, even after clicking on that item, it is not initiating onClick